# How to implement linkedin authentication/data sharing with multi party?

Tags: design, architecture, security, software, authorization

[image]

Hi I am working on application 2. 
My application interacts with application 1 and 3.
Clients of application 1 need to be to share their linkedin profile information with application 3. 
I have created a simple authorization to linkedin and presented it to application 1 as api. 
I now would want to build :
1) Either data sharing functionality between application 1 and 3 
OR
2) be able to forward authentication request from application 3 and 1.

Goal : is user to be able to share linkedin profile information with consent from application 1 to 3 which are connected by application 2.

It would be great if you could suggest me the best and most secure and easy way to implement this.

Your views will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It would be helpful if you directly redirect to the linked in site and after that if confirmation is true than just you nwed to make user accessible and display its information regarding to the content.